# Access salesforce sandbox using zkSForce

Tags: ios, salesforce, sandbox

I have used **zkSForce** in my iOS application to log in to SalesForce. Now I need to access the same data in sandbox environment for the same application.

But when I am trying to log in I am getting the following error.

**Error Domain=APIError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (APIError error 0.)" UserInfo=0xad3ef20**

```
{faultstring=INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out., faultcode=INVALID_LOGIN}
```

But when I am trying to connect to production environment I am able to log in successfully. Is there any specific set of instructions to follow to connect to Sandbox using **zkSForce**? Thanks in advance.

--EDIT--

I am using the following method to log in.

```
[SFAccountManager setLoginHost:@"test.salesforce.com"];
[SFAccountManager setClientId:CLIENTID];
[SFAccountManager setRedirectUri:REDIRECTURI];
[SFAccountManager setCurrentAccountIdentifier:USERNAME];
[SFAccountManager sharedInstance].coordinator.credentials.instanceUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://test.salesfoce.com"];

[[FDCServerSwitchboard switchboard] loginWithUsername:username password:passwordToken target:self selector:@selector(loginResult:error:)];
```

and the result is handled by the following method

```
- (void)loginResult:(ZKLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error{
    if (result && !error){
        [[SFAccountManager sharedInstance].coordinator.credentials setAccessToken:nil];
        [SFAccountManager sharedInstance].coordinator.credentials.accessToken = result.sessionId;
    }
    else if (error){
        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login failed"     message:@"Error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [myAlertView show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Login requests for Sandbox need to goto a different endpoint than the default one for production, so you need to call setLoginProtocolAndHost: on the client object before calling login, e.g.

```
ZKSforceClient *c = [[ZKSforceClient alloc] init];
[c setLoginProtocolAndHost:@"https://test.salesforce.com"];
[c login:self.username password:self.password];
...
```

Comment: I have set the login host to the appropriate one i.e test.salesforce.com itself. But still its not working

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the perfect solution but adding the following line worked for me.

```
[[FDCServerSwitchboard switchboard] setApiUrlFromOAuthInstanceUrl:LOGINHOSTURL];
```

where LOGINHOSTURL is you host URL.

Thanks @superfell for giving me the hint

Comment: I don't know what tool you're using but there's no SFAccountManager class in ZKSforce. see http://github.com/superfell/zkSforce